# Cant view any folders or files inside users home folder using testdisk?

Tags: 16.04, data-recovery, testdisk, photorec

I have installed the testdisk using

```
 sudo apt install testdisk
```

and using this I want to view and recover some deleted files in ubuntu 16.04. I selected my linux partion in testdisk

```
 sudo testdisk /dev/sdax
 [proceed][enter]
 [None][enter]
 [Analyse][enter]
 [ext4>Quick Search][enter]
 [ext4][enter]
 [P]
```

then I went to `Directory /home/eka/` where I expected to see Desktop, Downloads plus other folders and files but now I am seeing only these files

```
.ecryptfs
.Private
README.txt
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop
```

Comment: That's because `eka`'s home directory is encrypted. Encryption would not make any sense when you could bypass it so easily.

Comment: I thought using `sudo` should solve that problem. Is there a way to see my home directory

Comment: `testdisk` is for partition recovery.  `photorec` is for file recovery.  `photorec` needs to be ran as `sudo`.  `photorec` is also installed with `testdisk`

Comment: Yes, if you remember the password, you can open the home directory encryption. Maybe this link and links from it will help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory and https://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/ ; You can easily find more links about it via the internet. Good luck :-)